# After Repo sync, there are no files in the directory

Tags: android, repository

I've setup a new Repo for Android source code, and after executing the repo sync, there are no files in the repo directory. Did I miss something?

I used:

```
repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git
```

> repo initialized in /home/tarandeep/code/Android

```
repo sync
```

...
It downloaded GBs of data (I can confirm via network monitor) and then nothing appeared in the Android directory.

Comment: I am facing issue like after 100% ,I am not back to terminal command screen.(It show 100% but still not getting download full)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a git repo in a hidden directory, `.git`.  "Hidden" just means it starts with a period.

When in doubt, you can use `ls -a` or `ls -al` (vertical) to see hidden directories.

However, you will generally interact with the repository using `git` commands, `repo` commands wrapping `git`, or a GUI equivalent.

Comment: coming from svn, cvs world, I would find that odd. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @taranfx, `svn` uses a `.svn` directory for each source directory.

Comment: I checked it out using repo, and I have a .repo directory

Comment: I am facing same issue. do "ls -a " ,                                1 1) getting files ".repo .. .".don't see anything else. What should I do ? 
2) Total folder size about 6 GB. Is source is there or not?

Comment: I also have the same issue with AndroEmbedded faced. Any help? Is there something wrong with gitconfig?

Comment: @lacuesta @AndroEmbedded I haven't used repo in awhile.  But you can try `ls -al .git .repo`.  If that doesn't help, try [tree](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree).

Answer (score 4):

I experienced this. Somehow I had configured repo incorrectly and it was depositing the source into my home directory rather than my working directory. I blew away all the .repo* directories/files in my home directory, then re-ran `repo init` and `repo sync` in the working directory. All was well after that.

Comment: I found it worked well in my case. Previously I was wrongly running repo init in home directory and even I ran repo init again in another directory, it still deposited all files to home. Great help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should select a branch using the `-b` option to `repo init`, rather than just syncing everything.  Then you will see the files show up properly.

For example:

```bash
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest \
          -b android-4.0.1_r1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to /home/tarandeep/code/Android (that is where you downloaded the repo) and hit **CTRL+H**.
You will now find a folder named ".repo".
This is your downloaded data.

Answer (score -1):

I meet the same problem. As far as I know, unless `repo sync` download all files success, the git will not check out projects. In my case, `repo sync` failed due to some reason. So I got nothing except a hided `.repo` directory after running `repo sync`.

Here are some known issues.
https://source.android.com/source/known-issues.html

Hope it helps you.