# Why can't I see any android source files in working Directory?

Tags: android, git, version-control, repository, android-source

I'm downloading Android source code using the following command.

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b Android-4.1.2_r1
repo sync
```

I've almost downloaded about 1.4 GB of files, but there is no source code in working directory. Working Directory has only one folder ".repo" (Which is about 1.4 GB and does not seem to include source code).

Is this correct way to download android source code? If not, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally Got answer.This is working as it should!

First it fills up .repo folder, which can be huge(10 GB). Only after that repo script downloads android source code.

References:

1. [After Repo sync, there are no files in the directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506024/after-repo-sync-there-are-no-files-in-the-directory)

2. [What are the purpose of the bare git repositories in .repo/projects/ created by the Android repo script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151712/what-are-the-purpose-of-the-bare-git-repositories-in-repo-projects-created-by)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with android you will want to install the Android SDK.  This page explains how:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

From the SDK Manager, found in the tools directory, you can download any version of Androids source code you would like.

Comment: I'm looking for Android platform source code and NOT just SDK source code.

Answer (score 0):

The Android source code actually has an empty `master` branch.

Unless you specify a particular branch to repo, it will always pull the `master` branch.

The reason that Android has an empty `master` branch for many of its repositories is because, the user is expected to use a particular version of the Android source rather than the latest.
(The latest is also typically a branch..but not `master`)

try something like this
`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1`
You should see files other than just the .repo folder

Comment: I am facing same issue. do "ls -a " ,                                1 1) getting files ".repo .. .".don't see anything else. What should I do ? 
2) Total folder size about 6 GB. Is source is there or not?